# How to rewrite this logarithmic update rule

Tags: probability, logarithms

I tried to rewrite the equation given below. I get stuck getting rid of the $ P(n|z_{1:t})$ on the left side. How can this be done?
$$
P(n|z_{1:t}) = \left[1+ \frac{1-P(n|z_{t})}{P(n|z_t)}  \frac{1-P(n|z_{1:t-1})}{P(n|z_{1:t-1})} \frac{P(n)}{1-P(n)}\right]^{-1}
$$
With:
\begin{equation}
L(n) = log\left[\frac{P(n)}{1-P(n)}\right]
\end{equation}

Can be rewritten to (how do I get to this?):
\begin{equation}
L(n|z_{1:t}) = L(n|z_{1:t-1}) + L(n|z_t)
\end{equation}

From: 'OctoMap: an efficient probabilistic 3D mapping framework based on octrees'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluating the reciprocal operation on the RHS of the first equation,  we can express $P(n|z_{1:t})$ as 
$$P(n|z_{1:t})=\frac{P(n|z_t)P(n|z_{1:t-1})(1-P(n))}{P(n|z_t)P(n|z_{1:t-1})(1-P(n))+(1-P(n|z_t))(1-P(n|z_{1:t-1}))P(n)}$$
Thus
$$1-P(n|z_{1:t})=\frac{(1-P(n|z_t))(1-P(n|z_{1:t-1}))P(n)}{P(n|z_t)P(n|z_{1:t-1})(1-P(n))+(1-P(n|z_t))(1-P(n|z_{1:t-1}))P(n)}$$
resulting in
$$\frac{P(n|z_{1:t})}{1-P(n|z_{1:t})}=\frac{P(n|z_t)P(n|z_{1:t-1})(1-P(n))}{(1-P(n|z_t))(1-P(n|z_{1:t-1}))P(n)}$$
Taking the logarithm of both sides leads to
$$\log\left[\frac{P(n|z_{1:t})}{1-P(n|z_{1:t})}\right]=\log\left[\frac{P(n|z_{1:t-1})}{1-P(n|z_{1:t-1})}\right]+\log\left[\frac{P(n|z_{t})}{1-P(n|z_{t})}\right]-\log\left[\frac{P(n)}{1-P(n)}\right]$$ 
Using the notation $L(n)$ we have
$$ L(n|z_{1:t})=L(n|z_{1:t-1})+L(n|z_{t})-L(n)$$
Examining the paper referenced (page $5$, bottom of first column of text), a uniform prior probability is assumed where $P(n)=0.5$, leading to $L(n)=0$, so that we have the desired update equation:-
$$ L(n|z_{1:t})=L(n|z_{1:t-1})+L(n|z_{t})$$

Comment: You are welcome, glad you found the answer helpful.